# Admin account won't load after update

Tags: 14.04, unity, updates, administrator, stable-release-updates

I'm only asking this question because any other answer I found online to this problem didn't help me resolve it.

Basically I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 system last night and it asked me to restart my system. When I restarted it and logged in to my admin account the Unity interface didn't load. I could only see my background and Ubuntu 14.04 written in the bottom right corner of the screen. No shortcuts work like Alt+Ctrl+t to open the terminal, the mouse right click doesn't work either. I can only access the terminal with Alt+Ctrl+F1. I restarted the system several times and it was the same every time. I can, however, log in to another account which is not an administrator account, and that's what I'm using right now, but I don't have access to all my files from my admin account which I normally use.

I tried a number of solutions that people said worked for them in similar circumstances but none of them worked. I even installed gnome to see if that will help, but it didn't. Again I could only log in to the other non-admin account which displayed gnome without a problem, but the admin account didn't move past the background after login.

I even tried booting to another kernel in advanced options but that didn't work either.

I found the following solutions online which I tried but none of them worked:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

---

Another one was:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

---

Also this one:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

---

And this one:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo shutdown
```

---

None of these worked. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Try this to login to the admin account, 

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]

Comment: I logged in to my admin account from the other account using sudo -i -u [admin_account_user] and was able to back up my entire home folder from there. I still can't access my firefox bookmarks though, which I also want to back up. I'm trying to figure out where firefox keeps the bookmarks on the file system. But other than that, I would still like to regain access to the admin account so I wouldn't have to reinstall the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have one user that works in the GUI and an admin that works in console mode, you have all you need to recover your system without re-installing it.

Log into the Admin account using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and type:

```
sudo adduser admin-new
```

Enter all info and then type:

```
sudo adduser admin-new adm 
sudo adduser admin-new cdrom
sudo adduser admin-new sudo
sudo adduser admin-new dip
sudo adduser admin-new plugdev
sudo adduser admin-new lpadmin
sudo adduser admin-new sambashare
```

log off and log on as admin-new *using the GUI* (if this doesn't work, report back here)

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

**Warning!** Do *not* try to be smart and do a `cp --recursive /home/admin-old/* /home/admin-new/` as this will copy the error(s) you have in your current user settings!!!

```
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Documents/* /home/admin-new/Documents
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Downloads/* /home/admin-new/Downloads
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Pictures/*  /home/admin-new/Pictures
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Templates/* /home/admin-new/Templates
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Desktop/*   /home/admin-new/Desktop
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Music/*     /home/admin-new/Music
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Public/*    /home/admin-new/Public
cp --recursive --no-dereference /home/admin-old/Videos/*    /home/admin-new/Videos
```

(Leave out the stuff you don't really need any more like the old Downloads directory or the Templates or …)

**You now have 99% of all your stuff back!** (if you do not have enough space to do the above all together, delete the original in-between copy commands)

If you want to copy any additional directories beyond those above, *make a full system backup first* because *one of the directories you **didn't** copy* contains the error.

Now do a: `deluser --remove-home admin-old`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was already able to copy everything from my old admin account, including the firefox bookmarks and was about to create a new admin account and just copy the old data back into this new account when all of a sudden everything in the old account started working again. I honestly don't know why it started working again but it just is, and that's the account I am using right now. None the less your solution was the same one I was about to apply just before my old account decided to cooperate again and load the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting rid of *all* settings by coping only the data files to a new user, there is one more option to try first:

```
rm /home/{affected user}/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This gets rid of the unity-related settings only, and for most problems like this, it is enough to get you back to a working state. It worked for me and saved hours of work compared to the other solution.

<sub>[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1292396/comments/2)</sub>

Comment: Hours?  Anyway, the solution above is a generic one that can be applied to any problem that is user-related and not system related...  But yours is good too, so upvoted!  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! You're right, your solution is more general. But in this case, mine is much quicker. If it saves hours... depends. ;)